# MVC 4- Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I got following error and i can't find any reason for this. I have view in correct folder as well.

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Account/GetUsers
```

My controller class code as below: i'm trying to get list of users in database and display.

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetUsers()
        {
            var availableProfiles = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);
// havent implement yet...
            return View();
        }
}
```

My view is as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<LibraryManagementWeb.Models.StaffModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetUsers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header" data-original-title="">
                <h2>
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                    <span class="break"></span>
                    Staff user Details
                </h2>
                <div class="box-icon">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                              <fieldset class="col-sm-12">
                            <legend></legend>      


                 <a href="@Url.Action("RegisterStaf", "Account")" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-zoom-in "></i> <span>Add</span></a>


</fieldset>                   

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

my folder hierarchy as below:

[image]

I call this view in my `_layout.cshtml` as follows:

```
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Account")"><i class="icon-user"></i><span class="hidden-sm">User Management</span></a></li>
                }
```

What can be the reason for this?

**Edit:** My route details are as follows:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your routes?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I Edited my question with my route details as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect I know what your problem is. In this code:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetUsers()
        {
            var availableProfiles = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);
// havent implement yet...
            return View();
        }
}
```

Note the `[HttpPost]` attribute. This causes that action method only to match when the page is submitted via `POST` - it won't match for `GET` requests. If you do not have a corresponding action method which accepts `GET` requests, you will get the 404 error.

From what you have in the method, it doesn't look like you need the `[HttpPost]` at all, anyway. Try removing that attribute, and try again.

Comment: thank you.. this is the reason... I removed  `[AllowAnonymous]` and `[HttpPost]` words... then it works properly.... thanks a lot.....